# Create a "Wheel of life" using Javascript and SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I might need you for an other problem i'm facing. i'm actually in a traineeship of 3 months, and my superior asked me to create a "Wheel of life" using SVG. So here is code I have so far :

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SVG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="formulaire">
            <label>Number of circles</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" id="cercle"/>
            <label>Number of sections</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" id="section"/>
            <button>Create</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <svg id="canvas" height="750" width="1910">
                
                         
             </svg>
              
        </div>
    </div>
    <scrip></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I've tried to first create circle, then create some lines to cut the thing in how many sections we asked for in the input.But find that even if I could do this, I should not because I need to be able to detect in which "case" i'm clicking on later.

At the end, the outpust must be something like this (without the colors, only the main circles for now, i'll figure this out later myself) :

[image: Wheel of life]

TL;DR
I need to create a Wheel of life (see pic above) with SVG from 2 inputs (see code above).

Already thanking you for answering this !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+canvas+pie+chart+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: If your input is only number of circles and sections, how do you specify text labels? Or you need to render your SVG without texts?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Dont need to bother about text and all for now, if I get to "draw" those circles i'm a happy man !

Comment: Do you have access to the original artwork, it looks like it could be an SVG, if so you could examine the SVG to see how it's built up.  I assume if it's got clickable zones, it will have clip paths and groups / layers and transforms.

Comment: @Keith I unfortnatly dont have the original artwork, but it would have helped a lot indeed, thank's for the suggestion tho !

Comment: Oh, that's is a shame.  Another suggestion then, maybe use something like Inkscape to first create the SVG, and then examine it's output.  The great thing about SVG's, is they are just Text files, and you can examine them to see how things are built up.  You could even maybe look for an SVG that's very similar to what you want.  A quick google search for `wheel of fortune svg` gives a few results.  Unfortunately I think the task you have been given is not a trivial one, and it's going to take some time.. :(

Comment: @Keith I've searched for SVG wheel and I found some ! It will surely help me a lot, thank you so much ! I'm one step further for sure !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an SVG with click handler (run the snippet in a full page).

Note that circles and sectors are zero-based.

```js
const createSvg = (circles, sections) => {
    const svg = d3.select('#canvas');
  const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
  const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));
  //console.log(width, height);
  svg.selectAll('g').remove();
  const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${width/2},${height/2})`);
  let i;  
  for (i = 0; i < circles; i++)
    g.append('circle')
        .attr('r', 40 + i * 30)
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .style('stroke', 'black');
  const radius = circles * 30 + 70;
  const angle = Math.PI * 2 / sections;
  let points = "";
  for (i = 0; i < sections; i++) {
    const x = radius * Math.sin(angle * i);
    const y = radius * -Math.cos(angle * i);
    g.append('line')
        .attr('x1', 0)
      .attr('y1', 0)
        .attr('x2', x)
      .attr('y2', y)
      .style('stroke', 'black');
    points += ` ${x},${y}`;  
  }
  const onPolygonClick = () => {
    const x = d3.event.layerX - width / 2;
    const y = d3.event.layerY - height / 2;
    
    const radius = Math.hypot(x, y);
    const circle = Math.abs(Math.ceil((radius - 40) / 30));
    let clickAngle = Math.atan2(x, -y);
    if (clickAngle < 0)
     clickAngle = Math.PI * 2 + clickAngle;
    const sector = Math.floor(clickAngle / angle)
    alert(`Clicked on Circle ${circle} / Sector ${sector}`);
  }
  
    g.append('polygon')
    .attr('points', points)
    .style('fill', 'white')
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('fill-opacity', 0.01)
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .on('click', onPolygonClick);
}


const onClickButton = () => {
    const circles = d3.select('#circles').node().value;
  const sections = d3.select('#sections').node().value;
  createSvg(circles, sections);
}
d3.select('button')
    .on('click', onClickButton);
```

```css
label {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0 8px 0;
}

button {
  margin: 12px 0 12px 0; 
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <div id="formulaire">
            <label>Number of circles</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" id="circles"/>
            <br/>
            <label>Number of sections</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" id="sections"/>
            <button>Create</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <svg id="canvas" height="700" width="700">
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you so much, have a great day !